# Bind array values to textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, grid

I am writing a Sudoku application in c# and WPF. I got the grids with my Textboxes so far, but now i want to fill it with a Array of Arrays (`[][]`).

For my first tests i found a way to do this manually.
XAML:

```
 <TextBox> Text="{Binding Path=Testarr[0][0]}" Name="testbox"></TextBox>
```

and in my xaml.cs:

```
testbox.DataContext = this;
```

So now my Textbox show the value which is initialized in Testarr[0][0].

For my Sudoku i have 81 textboxes, and i don´t want to initialize all of them manually, is there a way to do it simple?

Comment: Yes. MVVM. ItemsControl with ItemTemplate. But that would require learning something, so just write a perl script to generate all the XAML with bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) where it shows how to use an `ItemsControl` to create your grid.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 
        <!-- ItemTemplate -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Using a TwoWay binding, the user input will automatically be set to the matching view-model instance.